# I want to modify asp.net mvc page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a system already built using asp.net mvc, and have a page with several fields save these values on db, I want to remove some of these fields considering that the fields on database accept null values, is it necessary to remove the fields from the model or is it possible to only remove the fields from the cshtml page

Answer (score 0):

1. You can remove those from cshtml if you are not using those fields in any computation or business logic processing and those fields are set to allow null values in database. But it's best practice to remove fields from everywhere else they may create confusion later.
2. You need to remove those fields both from cshtml and model as well as from all the logic/computation related to those fields. And those fields are set to allow null values in database.
3. You need to remove those fields from everywhere cshtml, model, logic, database if they are being used in computation and set to not allow nulls in database.